# Windows 10 gives error when calling ShellExecute with verb that is registered

Tags: c#, windows-10, shellexecute

We have run into a strange problem and it seems we are not the only ones (see note at bottom).

The problem is that we want to call ShellExecute with the shell verb printto. We are checking if it is registered and if so, start a process. The registered verbs can be retrieved in [`ProcessStartInfo.Verbs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verbs(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.FileName = @"C:\test.jpg";
startInfo.Verb = "printto";
startInfo.Arguments = "MyPrinter";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

if (!startInfo.Verbs.Contains("printto"))
    throw new Exception("PrintTo is not supported!");

try
{
    Process.Start(startInfo);
}
catch (Win32Exception ex) when (ex.NativeErrorCode == 1155)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Somehow printto is NOT registered...");
}
```

When running Windows 10 with the Photos UWP app as default viewer, the console will print that a Win32Exception with code 1155 was raised, which means that the file type is not registered (for the given verb). If the (old) windows picture viewer is default, this works.

Please also note, that we are checking if the verb is registered and only call this if it is. It seems that Microsoft does something different here.

The big question is: Why do these two MS APIs do not play together anymore and how can we circumvent that?

**Note:**
There is an old discussion with an answer that is not particularly correct, but also a slightly different problem description:
[Windows 8 blows error on c# process for printing pdf file, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320704/windows-8-blows-error-on-c-sharp-process-for-printing-pdf-file-how)

I therefore decided to start a new question and hope that it is aligned with the SO principles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ProcessStartInfo.Verbs` property is somewhat broken as it does not consider the way how newer versions of Windows (Windows 8 and above afaik) retrieve the registered application. The property only checks the verbs that are registered for the ProgId defined under `HKCR\.ext` (as can be seen in the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/ProcessStartInfo.cs,75bd50346bca44e3,references)) and does not consider other places such as below the Registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.ext` or some other places, e.g. defined via Policy.

#### Getting the registered verbs

The best way is to not rely on checking the Registry directly (as done by the `ProcessStartInfo` class), but to use the appropriate Windows API function [`AssocQueryString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773471.aspx) to retrieve the associated ProgId:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileName = @"E:\Pictures\Sample.jpg";
        string progId = AssocQueryString(AssocStr.ASSOCSTR_PROGID, fileName);

        var verbs = GetVerbsByProgId(progId);

        if (!verbs.Contains("printto"))
        {
            throw new Exception("PrintTo is not supported!");
        }

    }

    private static string[] GetVerbsByProgId(string progId)
    {
        var verbs = new List<string>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(progId))
        {
            using (var key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(progId + "\\shell"))
            {
                if (key != null)
                {
                    var names = key.GetSubKeyNames();
                    verbs.AddRange(
                        names.Where(
                            name => 
                                string.Compare(
                                    name, 
                                    "new", 
                                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
                                != 0));
                }
            }
        }

        return verbs.ToArray();
    }

    private static string AssocQueryString(AssocStr association, string extension)
    {
        uint length = 0;
        uint ret = AssocQueryString(
            AssocF.ASSOCF_NONE, association, extension, "printto", null, ref length);
        if (ret != 1) //expected S_FALSE
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        var sb = new StringBuilder((int)length);
        ret = AssocQueryString(
            AssocF.ASSOCF_NONE, association, extension, null, sb, ref length);
        if (ret != 0) //expected S_OK
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    [DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint AssocQueryString(
        AssocF flags,
        AssocStr str,
        string pszAssoc,
        string pszExtra,
        [Out] StringBuilder pszOut,
        ref uint pcchOut);

    [Flags]
    private enum AssocF : uint
    {
        ASSOCF_NONE = 0x00000000,
        ASSOCF_INIT_NOREMAPCLSID = 0x00000001,
        ASSOCF_INIT_BYEXENAME = 0x00000002,
        ASSOCF_OPEN_BYEXENAME = 0x00000002,
        ASSOCF_INIT_DEFAULTTOSTAR = 0x00000004,
        ASSOCF_INIT_DEFAULTTOFOLDER = 0x00000008,
        ASSOCF_NOUSERSETTINGS = 0x00000010,
        ASSOCF_NOTRUNCATE = 0x00000020,
        ASSOCF_VERIFY = 0x00000040,
        ASSOCF_REMAPRUNDLL = 0x00000080,
        ASSOCF_NOFIXUPS = 0x00000100,
        ASSOCF_IGNOREBASECLASS = 0x00000200,
        ASSOCF_INIT_IGNOREUNKNOWN = 0x00000400,
        ASSOCF_INIT_FIXED_PROGID = 0x00000800,
        ASSOCF_IS_PROTOCOL = 0x00001000,
        ASSOCF_INIT_FOR_FILE = 0x00002000
    }

    private enum AssocStr
    {
        ASSOCSTR_COMMAND = 1,
        ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE,
        ASSOCSTR_FRIENDLYDOCNAME,
        ASSOCSTR_FRIENDLYAPPNAME,
        ASSOCSTR_NOOPEN,
        ASSOCSTR_SHELLNEWVALUE,
        ASSOCSTR_DDECOMMAND,
        ASSOCSTR_DDEIFEXEC,
        ASSOCSTR_DDEAPPLICATION,
        ASSOCSTR_DDETOPIC,
        ASSOCSTR_INFOTIP,
        ASSOCSTR_QUICKTIP,
        ASSOCSTR_TILEINFO,
        ASSOCSTR_CONTENTTYPE,
        ASSOCSTR_DEFAULTICON,
        ASSOCSTR_SHELLEXTENSION,
        ASSOCSTR_DROPTARGET,
        ASSOCSTR_DELEGATEEXECUTE,
        ASSOCSTR_SUPPORTED_URI_PROTOCOLS,
        ASSOCSTR_PROGID,
        ASSOCSTR_APPID,
        ASSOCSTR_APPPUBLISHER,
        ASSOCSTR_APPICONREFERENCE,
        ASSOCSTR_MAX
    }
}
```

#### Actually printing images

However, this does not solve your actual problem, i.e. printing an image on Windows 10. If your requirement is to just get the image printed out you can do so using the `PrintDocument` class from the `System.Drawing.Printing` namespace as described in this related post: [**Print images in C#**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750659/print-images-c-net):

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
pd.Print();    

private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("D:\\Foto.jpg");
    Point loc = new Point(100, 100);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);     
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It took me a while to evaluate and understand what's happening, but your solution makes sense. I still have to chew on the fact that Microsoft broke their own APIs though...

So thank you very much for jumping in!